# Найти позицию последнего вхождения символа - Bash

Tags: bash

У меня есть строка которая содержит список архивов

```
string="1.tar.gz 2.tar.gz 3.tar.gz"
```

Мне нужно получить из нее подстроку с последним архивом: то есть

```
string="3.tar.gz"
```

Для этого нужно, как я понимаю найти позицию последнего пробела (символ ' ') и извлечь подстроку с помощью

```
${string:position}
```

с position до конца. К сожалению, средства для нахождения позиции последнего вхождения в bash я не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

можно воспользоваться [встроенным в posix-совместимые оболочки средством parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> `${parameter##[word]}` — удалить наиболее длинный префикс

в вашем случае префиксом может служить `'* '` (любые символы, за ними — пробел).

пример:

```
$ string="1.tar.gz 2.tar.gz 3.tar.gz"
$ echo ${string##* }
3.tar.gz
```